# Meteor "login" method never invokes callback, blocks all future RPC calls

Tags: javascript, meteor, rpc, meteor-accounts

**The issue**

I'm encountering an issue that pops up semi-frequently on some of our production Meteor app servers where method invocations queue up but never run, despite successful ping/pong DDP messages (and subscriptions) sending.

**What I know so far**

It's extremely difficult to debug since it's a minified production bundle, but here's what I've found:

Opening Chrome console and calling methods works as expected (I receive `onResultReceived` callback and normal asynchronous callback). For example:

```js
Meteor.apply('someMethod', [], {
    onResultReceived: function() {
    console.log('results received');
  }
}, function(e, r) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log(r);
});
```

Properly logs:
`results received`
`null`
`someresult`

If I check my DDP connection's outstanding method blocks (`Meteor.connection._outstandingMethodBlocks`), it properly returns an empty array.

**Where it breaks**

The issue begins though, once I try to call a login method. To narrow down the issue, I call the Meteor `login` method by using apply, like so:

```js
var loginArgs = [{
  user: {email: 'user@site.com'},
  password: Accounts._hashPassword('secretpassword')
}];
var options = {};
options.onResultReceived = function() { console.log(arguments); };
Meteor.apply('login', loginArgs, options, function (err, result) {
  console.log('--')
  console.log(err);
  console.log('--')
  console.log(result);
});
```

Once this is run, the `onResultReceived` fires and returns properly with my userId, token and tokenExpires. The websocket message is visible in my devtools network tab. But for some reason, the callback is never fired.

If I check `Meteor.connection._outstandingMethodBlocks` at this point, there's still an object in it from my `login` method call, but the method block `methods` array is empty.

If I inspect `Meteor.connection._methodInvokers`, I can still see the MethodInvoker there with the following properties:
[image]

This completely breaks the client-side app and prevents any future Meteor methods from being invoked, despite the fact that I can still receive downstream messages from websockets (e.g. subscription data).

**Conclusions so far**

The only conclusion I can draw so far is that the `invoker._dataVisible` is never set to `true`, which means that the callback is never invoked. See [the "_maybeInvokeCallback" function check for _dataIsVisible boolean.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L437)

**Additional notes**

I can force the callback to *eventually* run by:

1. Calling`Meteor.connection._stream.reconnect({_force: true});`
   or
2. Copying the websocket message from my chrome network tab that has the "msg: result" and pasing it into `Meteor.connection._livedata_connected(msg)` as the `msg` parameter

**My question**

**What would prevent calling the RPC `login` from ever invoking a callback? How can I further get to the bottom of this?**

Comment: we've got a similar problem in our production environment, were you able to solve this in the end? The strange thing is, I cannot reproduce this problem in development, even when running in --production mode to get the same minified source. The problem only seems to occur on the production server on specific accounts (!) but I have not found out why certain accounts work and others don't.

Comment: @PeterPeerdeman we often have it when mongo timeouts occur. I can sometimes reproduce it locally if we do a mongorestore with the `--drop` option. We switched db providers from Compose to Atlas and haven't been experiencing it, but the issue is still largely unknown to us.